# Condition met but doesn't run

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

So i have this condition:
[image]

but when i check the workflow its met but it never goes into the if statement,
[image]

Any Idea why this is?

Answer (score 1):

It's likely a data mismatch. No =/= false in all cases.

Is "SentEmailsOut" a checkbox, choice, or free text column type?

Comment: Its a choice column, not located in the form itself but in the library.

Comment: It sounds like the choices are true/false, but the workflow is looking for yes/no.  Try changing "No" to "False" in your if-statement and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

In designer workflows, Some times wont work with Boolean values directly.
So first take the boolean field value into on local variable, then use this local variable for comparisons.

Hope this helps you :)